# Add boolean class to array of classes

Tags: java, c#, class, xamarin

I have some code written in Java which I want to convert to Xamarin (C#). How can I write this in C#?

```
private static final Class<?>[] mSetForegroundSignature = new Class[] { boolean.class };
private static final Class<?>[] mStartForegroundSignature = new Class[] { int.class, Notification.class };
private static final Class<?>[] mStopForegroundSignature = new Class[] { boolean.class };
```

I don't know how to get this "boolean.class" and "< ? >" also doesn't work.
Because then this gets called

```
Method mStartForeground = getClass().getMethod("startForeground", mStartForegroundSignature);
```

And then some wrapper for each like

```
if (mStartForeground != null) {
        mStartForegroundArgs[0] = Integer.valueOf(id);
        mStartForegroundArgs[1] = notification;
        invokeMethod(mStartForeground, mStartForegroundArgs);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c# equivalent to `Class<T>` is `Type`, and for `boolean.class` it's `typeof(bool)` - if you like to read more about c# reflection, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial). Here is the translated code:

Signatures:

```
private static readonly Type[] mSetForegroundSignature = new Type[] { typeof(bool) };
private static readonly Type[] mStartForegroundSignature = new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(Notification) };
private static readonly Type[] mStopForegroundSignature = new Type[] { typeof(bool) };
```

Get method object:

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mStartForeground = new this.GetType().GetMethod("startForeground", mStartForegroundSignature);
```

Invoke method:

```
if(mStartForeground != null) {
    mStartForegroundArgs[0] = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    mStartForegroundArgs[1] = notification;
    //invoke via reflection (it may be different to invokeMethod?)
    mStartForeground.Invoke(instance, mStartForegroundArgs);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but in this case it gives me on .Invoke this error
"Object type Java.Lang.Integer cannot be converted to target type: System.Int32"

_private Java.Lang.Object[] mStartForegroundArgs = new Java.Lang.Object[2];
is the type of mStartForegroundArgs_

Comment: I don't know what `Java.Lang.Object` and `Java.Lang.Integer` should refer to in .NET, but `Convert.ToInt32` then isn't the right way to convert `id` to an integer...

Answer (score 1):

In C# it is called Type instead of Class. Things are named a little differently:

```
private static readonly Type[] mSetForegroundSignature = new Type[] { typeof(bool) };
```